# Getting a php variable into javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Following situation:

I have a txt file which contains some text. I read it with PHP via "file_get_contents".
Now i want to submit multiple forms with some ajax request.
To do this i need to get the variable into JS.

```
var results = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($results); ?>";
```

doesnt work. It returns "Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

The string itself contains only characters, and maybe a few specials.
An example of the content is something like this:

```
Email: MyName@mail.net - Pass: ^s2p3r(s3cr3t& - City: aCity
Email: OtherName@mail.net - Pass: ^s2p3r(s3cr3t& - City: anotherCity
```

So why JS cant read that?

Thanks

EDIT:

in the html output it totally got correctly displayed. 
even with all special charaqcters like ^ , ( or &

(i edited the above string to what exactly would allready give me that error)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing special characters from php to javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200620/passing-special-characters-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: Can you show us the rendered html code?

Comment: It seems ok: http://jsfiddle.net/hugnyu81/ - what special characters does it include?

Comment: thanks for all your input guys. in the html render output it get displayed correctly. special chars are like ^, &, @, :, nothing that is not also on a common keyboard

Comment: If the rendered HTML has `var results =  "Email: MyName@mail.net - Pass: s2p3rs3cr3t - City: aCity"`, then there is nothing wrong with that statement. Did you check at which line the Unexpected token ILLEGAL is displayed?

Comment: i added some more special characters. and exactly that string gives me the illegal token error. using chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `$results` a JSON string?

If so, you want to parse it using

`htmlspecialchars(json_encode(json_decode($results,true)))`

so that the information can then be first decoded into an array, then encoded as Javascript-ready JSON.

The only problem I see with that is that you seem to not be using valid JSON in that it is not in the proper quotes so depending on the version of PHP you are using, it may or may not be able to parse the data. The ideal situation would be for your data to look like

```
['Email' : 'MyName&mail.net', 'Pass' : 's2p3rs3cr3t', 'City' : 'aCity']
```

This will save you the headache of trying to use a regex to parse the information into a readable format, since there are time the regex could incorrectly replace/parse information that you may need. Still I believe that decoding and encoding the data using JSON should work.

Comment: its not a json string yet, but i want to send it as such later, via ajax request.

Comment: Yeah, so what you want to do is make it into a JSON string using what I mentioned above so that it can be read as JSON by Javascript. If you are using PHP 5.5 or 5.6, the above should be parsed correctly into JSON.

Comment: ahh, now i understand. plus you saved me some time for my next step. haha, it works. you sir, are as genius. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the Unicode U+200B Zero-width space character ? That character is known to cause the Unexpected token ILLEGAL JavaScript syntax error.

If your intent is to send that string to another request why dont your json encode your content?

or try this

`str_replace("\xe2\x80\x8b", '', $str);`

Answer (score 0):

Following like is something you looking for?

```
     <?php
       $var='MyName@mail.net - Pass: s2p3rs3cr3t - City: aCity';
     ?>

      <script type="text/javascript">
      var mymail = '<?php echo json_encode($var); ?>';
      alert(mymail);
      </script>

      if not, could you please tell the exact output you want..
```